# AOSP building : hiddenapi: No DEX files specified

Tags: java, android, build, android-source, android-embedded-api

I am building android repo to flash it to a rpi, and arround 80% of the process it failed.
this is the log

[  0% 3/6424] build out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/classes.dex
FAILED: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/classes.dex
/bin/bash -c "(rm -rf out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/ ) && (mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/ ) && (find out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex/ -maxdepth 1 -name "classes*.dex" | sort | xargs -I{} cp -f {} out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/ ) && (find out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-xml_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/ -name "classes*.dex" | sort | sed 's/^/--dex=/' | xargs out/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi --light-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt --dark-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-dark-greylist.txt --blacklist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-blacklist.txt )"
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47] No DEX files specified
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47] Command: out/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi --light-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt --dark-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-dark-greylist.txt --blacklist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-blacklist.txt
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47] Usage: hiddenapi [options]...
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]   --dex=: specify dex file whose members' access flags are to be set.
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]       At least one --dex parameter must be specified.
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]   --light-greylist=:
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]   --dark-greylist=:
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]   --blacklist=: text files with signatures of methods/fields to be marked
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]       greylisted/blacklisted respectively. At least one list must be provided.
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]   --print-hidden-api: dump a list of marked methods/fields to the standard output.
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]       There is no indication which API category they belong to.
hiddenapi E 01-17 22:47:24  3157  3157 hiddenapi.cc:47]
[  0% 8/6424] //prebuilts/sdk/current/extras/material-design:android-support-design-bottomappbar javac
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
22:47:55 ninja failed with: exit status 1

failed to build some targets (02:36 (mm:ss))

Can anyone help and explain to me the source of this problem and thank you in advance.

Comment: Ever get an update on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Android x86, for some reason the source `.dex` files in `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/ims-common_intermediates/dex` were not created for me (maybe due to previous errors in the compilation process).

I solved it by removing the entire `JAVA_LIBRARIES` directory, which caused - among others - the dex files to be rebuilt in the next compilation attempt:

```
rm -r out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
```

Maybe removing a subdirectory like `ims-common_intermediates` or `ims-common_intermediates/dex` suffices, but I didn't test that.